# Generate column value based on previous rows

Tags: mysql, sql

A table sorted by time with time and value, I want to add a column called Keep which denotes which row to keep. The keep column is either 0 or 1 for each row.

Criteria to keep a row:

1. If time between each row and previous row is greater than 5 minutes, keep this row; if the current row has a different value than the previous row, keep this row. (keep = 1)
2. If time between the previous row and this row is less than 5 minutes, and the value is the same, then mark it 0 for the keep column. The next row will not use the current row to calculate time difference, it'll use the previous row.

Example with output:

```
+--------+-------+------+
|  Time  | Value | Keep |
+--------+-------+------+
| 11:34  |   150 |    1 |
| 11:35  |   150 |    0 |
| 11:40  |   150 |    1 |
| 11:40  |   151 |    1 |
| 11:41  |   151 |    0 |
| 11:43  |   152 |    1 |
| 11:44  |   152 |    0 |
| 11:50  |   152 |    1 |
+--------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Your logic doesn't work for me. For example if the difference between current an previous is three minutes then 'if the current row has a different value than the previous row, keep this row' is true and 'If time between the previous row and this row is less than 5 minutes' is also true. Also in the statement 'If time between the previous row and this row is less than 5 minutes, and the value is the same' - the and portion should probably be OR.

Comment: If time between the previous row and this row is less than 5 minutes, and the value is the same. This should be AND. So in your example, if the difference between current and previous is 3 minutes, and if the value is the same as the previous, then keep, if not the same then don't keep.

Comment: The next criteria is that a row will not compare itself with a previous row if the previous row has a keep value of 0. it will compare to a row above where the keep value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from t t2
                where t2.time < t.time and t2.time >= t.time - interval 5 minute and
                      t2.value = t.value
       ) as keep
from t;
```